# Why is my variable changing values in recursive call in my C program?

Tags: c, variables, memory, recursion

I wrote a program to find the largest number in an array. The problem is that every time the `find_largest` function is called recursively, the `largest` variable seems to be filled with garbage from somewhere else in memory. I've stepped through it with a debugger and it seems to be working fine until the recursive call. The pointers for the array and the update to `largest`, if applicable, show expected values.

```
/*This program will find the largest integer in an array. It was written to practice
using recursion.*/

#include <stdio.h>
void find_largest(int *a, int n);
int main() {
    int a[] = {10, 27, 101, -8, 16, 93}; 
    int n = 6, i = 0;
    printf("Current array: ");
    while(i < n) {//print array
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    find_largest(a, n);
    return 0;
}//end main

//This function will start at the last element, and then step through the array 
//in reverse order using pointers. 
void find_largest(int *a, int n) {  //formulate the size-n problem.
    int largest = 0;
    if(n == 0) {    //find the stopping condition and the corresponding return
        printf("\nThe largest number is: %d \n", largest);
    }
    else { //formulate the size-m problem.
        n--; //decrement so that the proper number is added to pointer reference
        if(largest <= *(a + n)) //check if element is larger
            largest = *(a + n); //if larger, assign to largest
        find_largest(a, n); //recursive call
    }
}
```

The program returns zero as the largest integer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`largest` isn't shared by all of your recursive calls, each gets its own copy.  That means in the base case, you execute this code:

```
int largest = 0;
if (n == 0) { 
    printf("\nThe largest number is: %d \n", largest);
}
```

Where `largest` will *always* be `0`.

You can make `largest` `static` and it will work, though it's a bit of a strange way to go about it.  I'd prefer to do something like this:

```
int find_largest(int *a, int n)
{
    int subproblem;

    // base case - single element array, just return that element
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return *a;
    }

    // recursion - find the largest number in the rest of the array (increase 
    // array pointer by one, decrease length by one)
    subproblem = find_largest(a + 1, n - 1);

    // if the current element is greater than the result of the subproblem,
    // the current element is the largest we've found so far - return it.
    if (*a > subproblem)
        return *a;

    // otherwise, return the result of the subproblem
    else
        return subproblem;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely *a* bug with the code, but that doesn't explain why a zero-initialized variable is filled with "garbage" rather than just 0.

Comment: It's probably not - debugger artifact or OP is misreading, probably.  Anyway, the OP's question was "The program returns zero as the largest integer. Any ideas?"

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still having a little trouble following this code. Which two numbers are compared first?

Comment: The last two - 16 and 93 in your case.

Comment: Your solution might be better, but I am unable to follow it.

Comment: What's the problem?  I'll add some comments.

Comment: I wasn't grasping how the stack is filled with each variable until the base case is reached. I think I have a better idea now.

Answer (score 3):

`largest` is initialized to `0` in each separate function call, here's a quick fix:

```
int find_largest(int *a, int n) {  //formulate the size-n problem.
    static int largest = 0;
    if(!n) {    //find the stopping condition and the corresponding return
        int answer = largest;
        largest = 0;
        return answer;
    }
    else { //formulate the size-m problem.
        n--; //decrement so that the proper number is added to pointer reference
        if(largest <= *(a + n)) //check if element is larger
             largest = *(a + n); //if larger, assign to largest
        find_largest(a, n); //recursive call
    }
}
```

The `static` attribute tells the compiler that you only want to initialize the variable once, and afterwards it should retain it's data. This will fix your problem because after each recursive call, `largest` wont be reset to zero. Instead, it will contain the value of the last call (in this case, the calling function).

At the end of the function, you should reset `largest` to `0` so that in the next call, it doesn't still contain the value of the call previous. This is also why a temporary variable is made - so that it can return its value before it's set to `0`.

Comment: This seems the simplest fix but I'm not sure that's true recursion.

Comment: @CarlNorum posted an more elegant answer you should check out

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call find_largest(), you're creating a local variable int largest and assigning it the value of zero. So when n finally reaches zero, it doesn't really care what the past 5 recursive calls have done, it simply returns the zero to which you just set largest. Either make largest global, or pass it as a parameter to the function (probably better practice).

Comment: I tried passing it as a parameter and it worked, even up above with only two formal arguments. That's bad practice though, I'm assuming?

Answer (score 0):

make the int largest=0; into static int largest=0; it may help.By adding static the variable largest will be initialized only once throughout your recursion.